# How to prevent to ViewPager shows next page if next page is creating still in Android

Tags: android, multithreading, events, view, android-viewpager

I create my page view from images on sd card, and it take some time (around 2 seconds). All operations I do in thread. When thread is finished, the isCreated flag set as true.

How do I prevent to show next page of ViewPager if isCreated is false?

I must override touch event?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you have some choices to do that:

- you can tell the user in a progress dialog "Please wait, loading images ... blah"
- you can disable page scrolling by extends the ViewPager: overwrite the function "canScroll"
  and handle by your self if a user can scroll to the next/previous page

Answer (score 1):

This may helps you to override VIewPager . http://blog.svpino.com/2011/08/disabling-pagingswiping-on-android.html